# Apply Conditional Format to Multiple Columns with Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am creating an onEdit(e) function to update my charts format, based on column A's value. I have Column A set up to format appropriately with Conditional Formatting and a Data Validation drop down menu, but how can I make the other columns adjacent to the updated cell the same format?

See code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {

// Get current active sheet
  var actSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the integer value of the location the change is made at
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  // Define the max range in columns
  var max = actSh.getLastColumn();

  // Set a range to apply the conditional rule to
  var range = actSh.getRange(row,(col+1),1,(max-1));

  if (col == 1) {
    // Get Rule for Column A
    var rule = e.newConditionalFormatRules().copy();
    var newRule = range.setConditionalFormatRules(rule);
  }
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the spreadsheet I am trying to get the editor working on, for reference to what I am trying to accomplish.
[See Link below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m4Nr.png)

Comment: Define `adjacent`. Do you mean all cells within the same row?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

### How to extend conditional formatting over new ranges

The steps are the following:

- Retrieve the sheet of interest
- Retrieve the conditional rules for this sheet with `getConditionalFormatRules()`
- Loop through all the rules
- Retrieve the `ranges` for each rule with `getRanges()`
- Loop through the ranges to verify that the your column of interest is one of the ranges
- If the rule was found to be applied to your column of interest (`if(ranges[j].getColumn() == 1)`) - make a copy of the corresponding rule with `copy()`
- Assign a range of interest to the new copied rule with `setRanges([range])` and finish the request with `build`
- Add the new rule to the array of already exisitng rules with `push()`
- After exiting all loops, update your sheet with the new set of rules with `setConditionalFormatRules(rules)`

**Sample**

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  // Get current active sheet
  var actSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  // Get the integer value of the location the change is made at
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();  
  // Define the max range in columns
  var max = actSh.getLastColumn();  
  // Set a range to apply the conditional rule to
  var range = actSh.getRange(row,(col+1),1,(max-1));  
  if (col == 1) {
    var rules = actSh.getConditionalFormatRules();
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
      var ranges = rules[i].getRanges();
      for (var j = 0; j < ranges.length; j++){
        if (ranges[j].getColumn() == 1){
          var rule = rules[i].copy();
          rule.setRanges([range]).build();
          rules.push(rule);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    actSh.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Class ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule)
- [Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)